# I need to Update one value of a field that contains multiple values. I have tried Top 1, Min, Max, and I cannot get it to work

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-2016

I am trying to update one contact value out of many per company to be the default. I don't care which contact, but there can only be one default.

Here is an example of the layout

```
Table: companyemail
Company field: cmp_id 6-8 digit varchar
Contact field: contact_name 50 digit varchar
Default Contact: ce_defaultcontact possible boolean values is Y or N
```

I have these data

```
Company: ABCDEF
Contact: John Doe  Default: N
         Jane Doe  Default: N
         John Smith Default: N
```

And this exists on many company's. I am trying to update the table in sql to only set 1 contact as the default. I have tried the following

1.

```
update companyemail
   set ce_defaultcontact = 'Y'
   where contact_name = (
   Select Top 1 contact_name 
          From companyemail
          Where ce_defaultcontact = 'N'
          Order by contact_name DESC )

 FAIL (Only set 1 contact to Y)
```

2.

```
update companyemail
   set ce_defaultcontact = 'Y'
   where contact_name = (
   Select Max(companyemail.contact_name) from companyemail)
```

FAIL (Error)

Answer (score 0):

Use updatable CTEs and `row_number()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select ce.*, row_number() over (partition by cmp_id order by newid()) as seqnum
      from companyemail ce
     )
update toupdate
   set ce_defaultcontact = 'Y'
    where seqnum = 1;
```

I am guessing that `cmp_id` identifies the companies.  If that's not the right field, then use the correctly field in the `partition by`.

Comment: Do I enter newid() just like that, or is that supposed to be an actual value?

Comment: @MDaniel . . . `newid()` imposes a random order.  You can actually put anything there (although SQL Server doesn't allow a constant).  The `row_number()` guarantees that only one row will have "1".  The `order by` controls which one.

Comment: Thank you. That works with newid() just fine, and accomplishes exactly what I need.